# How can I replay a cut scene that I accidentally skipped?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I am playing the mission "Bury the Hatchet" and I accidentally skipped a major cut scene.... Is there any way to replay it besides reloading to a previous save?

Comment: I don't know if it works, so i write it as a comment. In the menu you can replay missions. I never used it, but maybe there you watch the scene again...?

Comment: @dTDesign Confirming that using this functionality lets you watch all the cut scenes again for Missions and Strangers & Freaks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Nick Bayley's confirmation to my comment, you are able to rewatch all cut scenes of all missions (main-story and strangers & freaks) when you restart this mission.

Pause game. Go to missions tab. Replay mission of your choosing.

*Thanks to Nick Bayley for checking*

Comment: Yes, finish the current mission and then replay it. AFAIK, when you replay a mission, your current position is saved and you will return to that exact position once the replayed mission is finished.

Answer (score 0):

All cut scenes are here in this video. Skip to the scene you missed and watch it :)

Comment: Who the hell downvoted this. This is the exact answer to the question. I accidentally skipped a cut scene and then found the scene I missed and watched it. Took 2 seconds. Hell of a lot faster than replaying the whole mission ??? 